# Insert text after 4 decimal variable number in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a processing file in Excel VBA to take raw data from our very old database software and arrange the `.txt` output into an Excel database. The problem I am running into is that I need to add a delimiting marker after a number sequence to tell Excel to split this part of the text string into two columns. The number sequence ranges from `0.0000` to `999.9999` and I need to keep this number intact. The number is always represented with four decimal points.

Could someone please give me some direction on how to accomplish adding a character (like Æ) after a variable number sequence for all cells within a column?

**Raw data:**

> A1: Hello World, This is a test of 22.5010 and is only a test
>
> A2: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250 and is only a test
>
> A3: Hello World, This is a test of 0.0000 and is only a test

**Final Result:**

> A1: Hello World, This is a test of 22.5010Æ and is only a test
>
> A2: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250Æ and is only a test
>
> A3: Hello World, This is a test of 0.0000Æ and is only a test

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the word immediatly after the number always the same? (In that case: "and")

Comment: Unfortunately the only constant is the four decimals places. The word preceding the number changes as well as the words following it.

Comment: Can there be other dots (`.`) before the numbers?

Comment: There are situations where there is a single period further in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the proper references to the project (in tab **Tools>References**):
Add "**Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**"

[image: Reference]

Now add a button onto your excel page and double click on the button to open the proper macro page. Add his code to the macro page it just opened:

```vb
Sub Button1_Clic()
'
' Button1_Clic Macro
'

'This sub will scan through the first column (A) and add Æ to the end of
'numbers with the proper format.

On Error Resume Next 'Needed incase the line doesn't have a number

Dim i As Integer
Dim NumberStr As Object

Dim RegEx As RegExp
Set RegEx = New RegExp
With RegEx
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = "\d{1,3}\.\d{4}"
End With

For i = 1 To 500 'Change last value to the last row in the column

    Set NumberStr = RegEx.Execute(Range("A" & i).Value)
    Range("A" & i).Value = RegEx.Replace(Range("A" & i).Value, NumberStr(0).Value & "Æ")


Next i

End Sub
```

This regex `"\d{1,3}\.\d{4}"` reads :
- Numeric character between 1 to 3 times repeated `\d{1,3}`
- Dot `\.`
- Numeric character repeated 4 times `\d{4}`

More info on [Regexes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial).

Comment: I've never really understood Regexes, but I think I should start doing some reading

Comment: @MichaelKosir, Whenever I want to use Regexes, I open the [link I provided](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial). This has a nice explanations of Regexes and all their possible commands.

Comment: I am having trouble getting Regex off the ground. Any thoughts on the sub below?      Sub Test2()
'Dim RegEx      As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

Range("A4").Value = RegEx.Replace(Range("A4").Value, "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{4}\b", "$0Æ")
End Sub'

Comment: @Jeff I updated the answer with an example loop to get you started. Does it help?

Comment: Is imports going to work in Excel 2013 VBA? Sorry for all the back and forth on this. Still cannot get it to run. Just hanging on the imports when compiling. Trying to use "Dim regEx As new VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp" to bring in RegEx but then your macro doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeff, Don't worry, we'll get it to work `:)`. Don't use your dim, just use my sub alone. You just need to link my sub to a button press or similar. I'll get back to you on this tomorrow, I'll get it into my excel to verify I got everything fine.

Comment: @Jeff I updated my answer to loop through, feel free to try it!

Comment: @Jeff, I just updated and verified that my code works properly, turns out I wrote `VB.NET` instead of `VBA`. Here is the **working** `VBA` code.

Comment: @Jeff, sorry for the spamming, I just notice I left a debugging line in (`Range("B" & i).Value = [...]`). This line is useless, I edited my answer to remove it. I would suggest you to do the same. (I was using this line the be sure it took the number properly, simple debugging line).

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if a period occurs *after* the number.
This won't work if the period occurs *before* the number

Before:

> A1: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250 and is only a test
>   A2: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250 an.d i.s on.ly a te.st
>   A3: Hello W.orld, This is a test of 0.1250 and is only a test

After:

> A1: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250Æ and is only a test
>   A2: Hello World, This is a test of 0.1250Æ an.d i.s on.ly a te.st
>   A3: Hello W.orldÆ, This is a test of 0.1250 and is only a test

Code:

```
For cell = 1 To 3 ' ENTER MAX ROW
    Range("A" & cell).Value = Left(Range("A" & cell).Value, InStr(Range("A" & cell).Value, ".") + 4) & "Æ" & Right(Range("A" & cell).Value, (Len(Range("A" & cell).Value) - 4) - InStr(Range("A" & cell).Value, "."))
Next cell
```

Comment: Nice one, I was going to post an answer with regexes, but this is simpler IMO.

Comment: @Sifu I am assuming there aren't any periods before the number. I think this wouldn't work if a period existed before the number

Comment: Michael, this works great as long as there are no other periods in the string. I was trying to change out "." with "?.???? " in an attempt to get the code to do the same with four decimal places and a space afterwards. Unfortunately, as soon as I introduce any wild cards it identifies the beginning of the string as a match and applies the character accordingly.

Comment: This code will work even if there are periods after the number, but it won't work if there are periods before the number. Are there any cases where periods appear before the numbers?

Comment: There is usually another 8 digit number at the beginning of the string which begins with a period that needs to be avoided. i.e. .12345678

Comment: And this occurs before the number you want to add the character to?

Comment: Sorry, yes... just realized I left that out.

Comment: I don't think you need the On Error Resume Next because the program is not actually returning an error. It is just an error because we say it is an error. My wording was incorrect in my answer, I will fix it